# Getting tracking code and session settings by API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I get the tracking code and session settings, using the Google Analytics Management API?

I am reading this API documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/list

I was able to get a list of all properties that I have on Google Analytics, but the session settings and tracking code is not returned by this API call.
By session settings I mean the following:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en

Is there any API endpoint that I can use to get these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the session & campaign timeout settings are not present in the [`webproperty` resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource) (I'm not sure what you mean by `tracking code`). All you get is this:

```
accountId
childLink
childLink.href
childLink.type
created
defaultProfileId
id
industryVertical
internalWebPropertyId
kind
level
name
parentLink
parentLink.href
parentLink.type
permissions
permissions.effective[]
profileCount
selfLink
starred
updated
websiteUrl
```

So unfortunately at this stage you just can't retrieve that info with any of the APIs.

That being said, they released a [`v4` for the reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) with more features, so they might also release a `v4` for the management API with more features in it.

Comment: Thanks Max! by tracking code, I meant this part: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080 It is very likely that this is also unavailable too.